# The location of `nicht` when saying 'don't spit on the floor!' in German

Tags: negation, imperative

I can think of

```
1. Spucken Sie nicht auf den Boden!  
2. Spucken Sie auf den Boden nicht!
3. Spucke nicht auf den Boden!  
4. Spucke auf den Boden nicht!
```

Are all these four gramatically correct or normally used?
(google translator shows only one and I'm not sure how much I can change it)

ADD :
I tried deepl.com and found
5. `spuckt nicht auf den Boden.` (I guess this is for plural you) and
6. `nicht auf den Boden spucken`.
Is 6 also correct? (I understand the `nicht auf den Boden` can come first to put stress on 'Not on the floor', but I am not sure if it's correct because the imperative form in the dictionary is `spucke` not `spucken`..)

Comment: 5. (= plural of 3.) and 6. are corrrect. Perhaps 6. has a more official touch and you could you find it on a prohibition sign ("No spitting ..."). See [this example](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datei:Zusatztafel_Nicht_%C3%BCberholen_-_No_Passing,_StVO_1953.svg).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, *Sie* or *du* doesn't make a difference here.  Now, (1) and (3) are definitely correct and idiomatic.  (2) and (4) are in all practical scenarios incorrect, but had their usages in poetic language; they remind me of Struwwelpeter (19th century poetry intended to "pedagogically" scare children):

> Messer, Gabel, Scher' und Licht
>
> sind für kleine Kinder nicht.

Comment: I see. that's clear now. Danke schön!

Comment: I tried deepl.com and found 1. `spuckt nicht auf den Boden.` (I guess this is for plural you) and 2. `nicht auf den Boden spucken`.  Is 2 also correct? (I understand the `nicht auf den Boden` can come first to put stress on 'on the floor', but I am not sure if it's correct because the imperative form is spucke not spucken..) I added to my question. :)

Comment: @ChanKim I would use "Nicht auf den Boden spucken!" when seeing someone (in particular a small child) preparing to do just that.

Comment: @Roland Thanks, but why do you use `spucken` not `spucke`? is it a reduced sentence for `spucken muss`?

Comment: @ChanKim https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperativ_(Modus)#Infinitiv

Comment: You could use (4) as sort of an hommage to Heinrich Hoffmann, but then it has to have a rhyme like "Spucke auf den Boden nicht, denn so etwas tut nur ein Wicht!"

Comment: I'm thinking (6) would be be seen on a sign in an institutional setting like a subway station.